# MSBuild and multiple Delphi versions

Tags: delphi, msbuild

I have a project for which I need to build two executables: one under Delphi XE2 and one under XE3. I have a build script which builds each version (i.e. one script for XE2 and one for XE3).

If I run the build script for the last version of the IDE I ran, all works well (i.e. run Delphi XE2, build app, run XE2 build script).

However if I run the build script having just run a different version of the IDE I get an AV as soon as my app starts (I.e. run Delphi XE2, built app, run XE3 build script).

It looks as though something about the build script is being cached/modified by the IDE and I need to restore the appropriate data for the version I want to build with. I've tried this with the .dproj, but no luck.

Or could it be loading form resources - both editions show errors due to non-existent properties at start up if the IDE. If so, is there an easy way around this without having maintain multiple versions of all the .fmx files?

Here's a sample build script:

```
set path=%path%;c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5
set path=%path%;c:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\10.0
set path=%path%;c:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\RAD Studio\10.0
set BDS=c:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\10.0
set FrameworkDir=c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\
set FrameworkVersion=v3.5

set failed=false
cd \myprogs\monkeystyler
msbuild monkeystyler.dproj /t:build /p:config=full||set failed=true
cd build
if not %failed%==true goto Done

echo ****FAILED TO BULD MONKEYSTYLER
****
Pause
exit

:done
```

Comment: Do they have the same output paths. Full clear out between builds or totally different output paths would be my first guess.

Comment: Do you run you scripts from the appropriate Rad Studio command prompt (which should set correct environment)?

Comment: Tony: I tried a /t:clean before the build with no difference. I assume that clears out everything.

Comment: Serg: I run from the DOS command line but the script should e setting everything necessary. I've added one of the scripts (the other is the same with different paths).

Comment: try crosschecking with the content of rsvars.bat which is in the ide's bin folder.

Comment: did u try specialized build tools like Lazy Builder or DelphiPi ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went back to my suspicion that it was the form file resources.

My theory was that the with the form files saved by the 'wrong' version of the IDE, when a project built with a different version tried to load them I was getting access violations due to the app trying to load data for properties which where not available in that edition.

To test this I got compiled the project successfully in one version of the IDE (XE3 in this case), did my automated build and tested that the app ran (it did).

I then loaded a .fmx file for the project and added a non-existent property to the form.

Build and the app fails same as before.

Remove the added property and build now succeeds.

All (!) I need to do now is write some code to parse the form files and remove any non-existent properties for the version I'm building.

Answer (score 7):

Let's take a look at this line in your XE3 script:

```
set path=%path%;c:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\10.0
```

My guess is that you follow that up in the XE2 script with:

```
set path=%path%;c:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0
```

At which point your path variable looks like this:

```
set path=%path%;c:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\10.0;c:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0
```

And so the second script fails because the paths from the first script appear earlier.

The elegant way to fix this is to use [`setlocal`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491001.aspx) and [`endlocal`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490898.aspx) in your scripts to isolate them from each other.

```
setlocal
set path=%path%;c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5
set path=%path%;c:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\10.0
.....
endlocal
```

The hacky way to fix it is to set the path like this:

```
set path=c:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\10.0;%path%
```

Please use the elegant approach!

---

What's more you should use pushd and popd to isolate directory changes to each script.

If this doesn't solve everything, do give more information. For a start, error messages are very useful.

Comment: +1 for a good correction, but it hasn't solved the original problem.

Comment: Well, it's the best I can do here. You didn't show any detailed error messages, so I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

The last IDE that you run will update the EnvOption.proj in your `<user>\AppData\Roaming\Embarcadero\BDS\<version>`folder.

This contains all your search paths, among other things.

This file is indirectly included in your project. So if you run say `XE2's IDE` then compile your `XE3` app, you will get the wrong paths.

You will probably want to disable that and explicitly specify your search paths in each project's dproj file.

`e.g. msbuild myproj.proj /p:ImportEnvOptions=false`

This is my best guess. Sorry if it's 5 years too late. I have just struggled with similar issues!

All the best

Steve

Comment: I had the same issue after installation of a newer Delphi version 10.3. My project was still on De 10.2.

In order to initate the enviroment variables I called the batch rsvars.bat delivered from Embarcadero from the C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\<Version No>\bin.

The only change which was nessesary yet was to define the right path to the required delphi version:

`call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\bin\rsvars.bat"`
`msbuild.exe MyProj.dproj /t:Rebuild /p:Config=Release;Platform=Win64`